# C++: Join an array of WCHAR[]s?

Tags: c++, string, unicode

I have an array of WCHAR[]s. How can I join them?

I know the array length.

```
[L"foo", L"bar"] => "foo, bar"
```

Answer (score 4):

Loop over those strings and add them to a `std::wstring`:

```
std::wstring all;

wchar_t *data[] = { L"foo", ... };
size_t data_count = sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data);

for (size_t n = 0; n < data_count; ++n)
{
    if (n != 0)
        all += L", ";
    all += data[n];
}
```

Comment: +1 as it is the basis of my answer. Though I would replace the loop handling with what I have.

Comment: You should change `int n` to an unsigned type (preferably size_t). Otherwise compilers will complain.

Comment: @BillyONeal - thanks for calling out the `int` / `size_t` issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does your system have `wsprintf()`?  Example:

```
wchar_t *a = { L"foo", L"bar" };
wchar_t joined[1000];

wsprintf(joined, "%S, %S", a[0], a[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good job for a template function. I use this function for joining strings, but it takes any container that supports forward iterators:

```
template<typename oT, typename sepT, typename rT = oT> rT joinContainer(const oT & o, const sepT & sep) {
    rT out;
    auto it = o.begin();
    while(it != o.end()) {
        out += *it;
        if(++it != o.end()) out += sep;
    }
    return out;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
vector<wstring> input = { L"foo", L"bar", L"baz" };
wstring out = joinContainer<vector<wstring>, wstring, wstring>(input, L", ");;
wcout << out << endl;
```

The output looks like this:

```
foo, bar, baz
```

Note: If you're not using C++11, you can declare the iterator like this instead of using `auto`:

```
typename oT::const_iterator it = o.begin();
```

Answer (score -2):

Slightly improved version of R Samuel Klatchko's solution.

```
wchar_t *data[] = { L"foo", ... };
size_t data_count = sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data);

wchar_t result[STUFF];

wcscpy(result, data[0]);
for (std::size_t n = 1; n < data_count; ++n)
{
    wcscat(result, L", ");
    wcscat(result, data[n]);
}
```

The improvement is that no if branch dependency is in the loop. I have converted to the C standard library's wcsXXXX functions, but I'd use a `std::wstring` if it is available.

EDIT:

Assuming

> I know the array length.

means, "I know the number of strings I'd like to join", then you can't use what I've posted above, which requires you know the final destination string length at compile time.

If you don't know at compile time, use this which works otherwise (and contains the loop improvement I was talking about):

```
wchar_t *data[] = { L"foo", ... };
size_t data_count = sizeof(data) / sizeof(*data);

std::wstring result(data[0]); //Assumes you're joining at least one string.
for (std::size_t n = 1; n < data_count; ++n)
    result.append(L", ").append(data[n]);
```

Comment: I would definitely use a std::wstring, unless you know how big to make STUFF. You should also add a null terminator.

Comment: @zdan: The OP explicitly specified that he knows the length. wcscpy and wcscat add appropriate NULL terminators -- none are required.

Comment: -1 for inviting a buffer overflow and for using the Shlemiel the painter's algorithm (http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Comment: @dan04: I agree that it'd be better to use a std::wstring. I'm posting this as an example of how the same thing might be accomplished using the C standard library. So long as the strings aren't huge, it's not going to matter anyway. (Shlemiel the Painter's Algorithm is the biggest reason the C string handling system sucks!). As for the buffer overrun, it's not going to buffer overrun if the OP knows the length in advance, as he has indicated.

Comment: @Billy: I interpreted the array length to be the number of input array elements, not the resulting output buffer size. Point taken about wcscat.